# Is it possible not to show dialog boxes in download function

Tags: abap

I'm using "**DOWNLOAD**" function of abap to download something as txt file. But "DOWNLOAD" function shows some dialog boxes that shows where the file is being downloaded and asks if there is another file with the same name I want to replace.

There is ***silent*** parameter for that function to import but it doesn't change anything when I assign *'m'* or *'s'* or *'x'* to that.

Here is what I do;

```
CALL FUNCTION 'DOWNLOAD'
  EXPORTING
    filename = fn
    filetype = 'ASC'
    silent   = 'M'
  TABLES
    data_tab = itab.
```

GUI_DOWNLOAD (obsolete) is ok without dialog boxes but I can not silence 'DOWNLOAD' function. Anyone knows how to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than the function modules you mention, you should use the methods of class `cl_gui_frontend_services`.

The following snippet shows you an example call to `cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download`.

```
types: t_line type c length 100.
data: lt_tab type table of t_line.
append 'test' to lt_tab.

call method cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download
  exporting
    filename = 'C:\temp\file.txt'
  changing
    data_tab = lt_tab[].
```

This downloads the file to the specified location without a dialog. For showing a file selection dialog if you choose, there is `cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog` or `cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_save_dialog`.

**Notes:**

1. You should check the return codes from the method calls. I just omitted them here for brevity, but failure to include them may result in a short dump.